# Ardour 3 Jackdbus not quitting

Tags: 14.04, sound, jack, ardour

Is there a solution to the problem of jackdbus not quitting after Ardour closes in Ubuntu 14.04LTS?
I have seen other references to the problem but no solution. My workaround is to launch System Monitor and 'kill' jackdbus manually. Not elegant but at least I get desktop audio back.
I would appreciate any help on this.

Many thanks,

Steve